# Efficient way to invalidate a child view when its parent ListView is scrolled?

Tags: android, listview, ondraw, invalidation

I have a ListView with a custom child view as its row  layout.  My requirement is to invalidate the row's child view  only when the ListView is scrolled. Right now I achieve this by calling ChildView.invalidate() from the child view's onDraw() method and things works very well as I expected, but this approach  also invalidates the child view even when the ListView is not scrolled, so I observe that it consumes a lot of CPU  when the app is running.  I am looking for an inexpensive solution for this. 
Is there any call back occured when the ListView is scrolled? I could not see anything.
Please answer, Thank you.

```
protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
   drawBackground(canvas);
   drawContent(canvas); 

   this.invalidate();//Recursive calling...? But no error or warnings issued.
   //super.onDraw(canvas);               
}
```

Comment: @pskink Thanks
It works! but did not solve the issue of "do it with an inexpensive approach". Please refer the comments in the code and answer what to do with arguments of onScroll() to only invalidate views which are visible on the screen.
View.getChildAt(int).invalidate does not work..

Comment: invalidate all the views of your ListView, whats wrong with it?

Comment: @pskink
Is it ok? as the doc says It "Causes all the views to be rebuilt and redrawn" Is this a good practice? Sorry if I am wrong or misunderstood about this.

Comment: @pskink
Here is the exact solution I was looking for.(refer the recent answer). It only invalidates a single child view, which is in visibility range. It works without any issue.

Comment: ok now try to Log.d lastVisibleItemCount and view.getChildCount and compare those rwo values, you will see that they are the same

Comment: @pskink
Yea, your are right, the lastVisibleItemCount is always high! 
But the last approach only invalidates the specific view.
Calling invalidateViews() results with unexpected behavior of the ListView, that, it becomes unresponsive to touches! row views are not colored when touched, and more over the CPU meter shows that it is extremely busy when the invalidateViews() is used!. When compared with this results, invalidating a specific view is so cool. =D

Comment: you want to invalidate only one specific view or all views in the listview?

Comment: My primary requirement is, to invalidate a specific view of every visible rows, so, When I tried with calling invalidate() within onDraw() of the child view subclass, it was heavily consuming the CPU, But when I tried with invalidateViews() it was working fine, but it also raised a few unexpected behavior in the ListView. eg:- No touch sounds, unresponsive to touches, etc. 
I am beginner, so your suggestion to use onScrollListner helped me  a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@pskink Thanks It works! but did not solve the issue of "do it with an inexpensive approach". Please refer the comments in the code and answer what to do with arguments of onScroll() to only invalidate views which are visible on the screen. View.getChildAt(int).invalidate does not work

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView;

public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity implements ListView.OnScrollListener {

...         

@Override    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);      
    setContentView(R.layout.list_activity_layout);          

    getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);    

}

....

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    Log.e("MyListActivity", "onScrollStateChanged()");
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    Log.e("MyListActivity", "onScroll()");
    Log.e("view.getId():", "" + view.getId());


    //view.invalidateViews();//Calling this method does the job, but it seems that It might re-measure                              
                            // and redraw each and every views of each and every rows in the ListView..!
                            // So, still it is an expensive approach. is it?, but better than doing
                            // recursive calling of invalidate(); am I right?
                            // I am not satisfied with this approach.

    // At least it should be possible to invalidate the views which are visible on the screen, as we expect from -
    // the arguments of this method.
    // Let me attempt to do it, shown below..               
    if(visibleItemCount != 0){
        int lastVisibleItemCount = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        for(int i=firstVisibleItem; i<lastVisibleItemCount; i++){
            if(view.getChildAt(i) != null){
                view.getChildAt(i).invalidate();// Not works.
            }               
            Log.e("view.getItemIdAtPosition(i):", "" + view.getItemIdAtPosition(i));
        }
    }       
  } 
}
```

@pskink Here is the exact solution I was looking for. It only invalidates a single child view, which is in visibility range. It works without any issue.

```
    @Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    //view.invalidateViews();//It does.., but still being expensive...!

    //The following only invalidates a single child view of the Row view in the visibility range.
    //Initializing i=0 may seem unnecessary, but it resolves many unexpected behavior of
    //the ListView when it is initialized to i=firstVisibleItem. 
    if(visibleItemCount != 0){
        int lastVisibleItemCount = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;;                        
          for(int i=0; i<lastVisibleItemCount; i++){
            mRowView = mListView.getChildAt(i);//returns the row view.
            if(mRowView != null){
                mChildView = (CustomChildView) mRowView.findViewById(R.id.custom_child_view);//Single child of the Row View.                
                if(mChildView != null){
                    mChildView.invalidate();//only invalidates the required Child view of the row view.
                }                                       
            }
            Log.e("Row view pos: ", "" + i);
        }
    }       
}
```